# Ubuntu 16.04 systemd vs. cups-lpd

Tags: printing, systemd, cups-lpd

Ubuntu 16.04 uses **systemd** for initialization.  For CUPS, they have three files - *cups.socket*, *cups.path* and *cups.service* to configure printing services.  Does anyone have the files for configuring **cups-lpd** under **systemd**?

Thank you...

Answer (score 1):

They're in the source:

- [`scheduler/org.cups.cups-lpd.socket`](https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/printing/cups.git/tree/scheduler/org.cups.cups-lpd.socket)
- [`scheduler/org.cups.cups-lpd@.service.in`](https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/printing/cups.git/tree/scheduler/org.cups.cups-lpdAT.service.in) (the package building process would convert the macros here)

The Debian/Ubuntu maintainers have not included them in any Debian/Ubuntu packages.