# Enable CUPS-LPD on Server 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, server, cups-lpd

How can I enable CUPS-LPD on Server 16.04 LTS?

I've looked at the answer to this Ask Ubuntu question [Ubuntu 16.04 systemd vs. cups-lpd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/846844/ubuntu-16-04-systemd-vs-cups-lpd) and it wasn't helpful.

Comment: I did not understand how to use it.  I am familiar with systemd through systemctl but I am unfamiliar with creating or adding new services to it, manually.  The answer I referred to gave me the pieces but not the solution to the puzzle.  I was hoping to get detailed instructions.  For legacy reasons I need the LPD service.

Answer (score 4):

So I got cups-lpd to work.  Here's how:

1. I created two files:

   cups-lpd.socket

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=CUPS LPD Server Socket
   PartOf=cups-lpd.service

   [Socket]
   ListenStream=515
   Accept=true

   [Install]
   WantedBy=sockets.target
   ```

   cups-lpd@.service

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=CUPS LPD server
   Documentation=man:cups-lpd(8)

   [Service]
   ExecStart=/usr/lib/cups/daemon/cups-lpd
   StandardInput=socket

   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target
   ```
2. I copied both files to /lib/systemd/system/
3. I ran this command: `sudo systemctl start cups-lpd.socket`, and `sudo systemctl enable cups-lpd.socket` to enable it on boot

Comment: Used this to enable cups-lpd socket in Lubuntu 18.04.5 and worked like a charm, helped me with sap print problem happening with linux terminals.